# get swapchain of any HWND window

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directx

I want to preprocess the look and feel of all the windows that are displayed on the desktopn. For this i would either need the swapchain of the entire desktop or the swapchain of all the windows on the desktop. So i was wondering if it was possible to get the swapchain of any window displayed on the desktop?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? And what do you mean by "swapchain"?

Comment: i want to apply some sort of image processing algorithm to every window that is being displayed on the desktop. Not sure if i am correct but almost every desktop app has a `swapchain` associated with it, which is finally rendered on the app's window.